# Probleme with canvas in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem with my code in html and i don't know why.
I explain this is my code :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="left: 200px;">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#navigation_bar" data-canvas="body">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<nav id="navigation_bar" class="menu menustandard offcanvas">
   Something
</nav>
```

Yet, I have include the right files boostrap css and js after jQuery.
And I don't have the icon just nothing, if I delete the class `navbar-toggle` i have a mini button without the 3 spans.
This is my screenshots:

**With the class :**

[image]

**Without :**

[image]

Can you help me please ? :)

Comment: Found ! Must add this to the css file :
`.navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}`

Comment: Add this as an answer and accept it, so that this question is no longer listed as "unanswered"

Comment: You're right i will do it thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Must add this to the CSS file :

```css
.navbar-toggle { 
   float: left; 
   margin-left: 15px; 
}
```